# Electron transport in metal/semiconductor contact before equilibrium

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm slightly confused as to the physical reasons for why in the metal and n-semiconductor contact shown below it is known that electrons will tend to flow from the semiconductor to the metal rather than vice-versa.

[image: ms-junction]

The explanation (as I understand it) for why electrons initially flow from semiconductor to metal before equilibrium is reached goes as follows: The fermi level of a material indicates the energy level with a 50% probability of occupancy. The probability of occupancy decreases as energy increases. Consider a conduction electron at an energy level $E>E_C$ on the semiconductor side. In the instant after the junction is formed (as shown in (a) in the figure), this conduction electron "sees" available states at the same energy $E$ on the metal side of the junction. Because $E_{FS} > E_{FM}$, the states at $E$ on the metal side are less likely to already be occupied, and so there is net transfer of electrons from the semiconductor to the metal (until the depletion region builds up and equilibrium is reached).

My confusion: this explanation seems to ignore the density of states / total electron density information for the metal and semiconductor. If the density of states were exactly the same on each side of the junction then I would agree with the above argument. However, my understanding is that in general the metal is going to have a much, much higher free electron density than the n-type semiconductor. So again considering the conduction electrons at some energy $E>E_C$, I would expect there to be many more electrons at this energy on the metal side than the semiconductor side, and so I would expect that because of this concentration gradient the electrons would diffuse from metal to semiconductor.

Have I made a misunderstanding of how to interpret the difference in fermi level between the two materials?

Comment: The density of states comes into play after the argument of the book figures out which direction to push the electrons. You are kinda confusing the "forces" or "temperature differences" with the "heat capacity" parts of the calculation. (Also, the problem sounds a little contrived, since the book assumed that the E_F of the semiconductor lies above E_F of the metal in the first place, which is already sufficient info to know which direction the electrons will flow.)

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Could you explain why knowing the relative positions of the metal/semiconductor $E_F$ levels is sufficient info to know the direction of electron flow? It's not clear to me why that's the case even if there's, e.g., a higher concentration of electrons on the metal side. Why wouldn't there be net diffusion of electrons into the semiconductor in that case?

Comment: It is sufficient, because it is saying that the pushing force is stronger on the semiconductor side. When you have two gas cylinders and you let the piston free to move, then the higher pressure side will expand and lower pressure side contract. The total amount of volume exchange depends upon the details as you expect, but the initial decision of which is the one expanding, is given by the pressure. Here, even though the sea of electrons in the metal looks like it is filled taller than the valence band, the correct thing to look at is the E_F, where semiconductor is higher.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure why the higher $E_F$ itself implies a higher "pushing force". I'm only really familiar with $E_F$ through its use in the Fermi function (only applicable at equilibrium anyway) where it just indicates the energy level corresponding to 50% probability of occupancy (if available). What other specific information about the electrons in the metal/semiconductor sides is $E_F$ giving here?

Comment: That is because it really isn't a random parameter. E_F is kinda badly named. It is easier to understand why it is important if you realise that it is the zero-temperature limit of the chemical potential of electrons. Once you see that it plays the same kind of behaviour as pressure does in exchanges of volume, it is easier to understand its significance to this problem